# VS Code enforces semicolons, but Angular TypeScript examples do not use consistently?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, tslint

I'm taking the Microsoft Angular Fundamentals course right now and I spotted lack of semicolons in their examples, something like:

```
gitSearch = (query: string): Promise<GitSearch> => {
    let promise = new Promise<GitSearch>((resolve, reject) => {
        if (this.cachedValues[query]) {
            resolve(this.cachedValues[query])
        }
        else {
            this.http.get('https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=' + query)
            .toPromise()
            .then( (response) => {
                resolve(response as GitSearch)
            }, (error) => {
                reject(error);
            })
        }
    })
    return promise;
  }
```

Notice they don't use semicolons after `resolve.thisCachedValues[query])`. But VS Code gives me TSLint warning `'Missing semicolon'` at that line. Is this an issue if I omit the semicolon?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it does make a difference. Typescript is an extension of Javascript and it has inherited some of it's properties. Take a look at below example:

Consider the
consequences of semicolon insertion on the return statement. If a return statement
returns a value, that value expression must begin on the same line as the return:

```
return
{
 status: true
};
```

This appears to return an object containing a status member. **Unfortunately, semicolon insertion turns it into a statement that returns undefined**. There is no warning
that semicolon insertion caused the misinterpretation of the program. The problem
can be avoided if the { is placed at the end of the previous line and not at the beginning of the next line:

```
return {
 status: true
};
```

So, make sure that semicolons are present at right place (mostly when a line ends in javascript). I hope this would give you some idea about the potential pitfalls if you do/do not put semicolon properly.

I have taken this example from **JavaScript: The Good parts** which is really a thin 172 pages but awesome book about such stuffs

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript has a syntactic feature known as **semicolon insertion**. Since Typescript is a strict superset of JavaScript, **semicolon insertion** applies to Typescript as well. This means that in most cases, *semicolons are not required*. Exceptions are detailed below.

## From [JavaScript Semicolon Insertion: Everything you need to know](http://inimino.org/%7Einimino/blog/javascript_semicolons)

> [T]he [ECMAScript] specification prose then gives rules which describe how the actual parsing differs from the formal grammar. These are described as though semicolons are inserted into the token stream while parsing, though this is just a specification convenience; in practice, parsers do not need to generate fake semicolon tokens, but can instead *regard semicolons as optional in specific places in the grammar* (for an example see [this parser expression grammar for ECMAScript](http://boshi.inimino.org/3box/PanPG/grammars/ECMAScript_5.peg), particularly the Statement, EOS, EOSnoLB, and SnoLB rules). Where the specification says that a semicolon is inserted, this simply means that the statement currently being parsed is ended.

## Where are semicolons optional and where are they required?

> - Firstly, a semicolon is optional only where there is a line break, a closing brace, or the end of the program.
> - Semicolons are not optional between statements appearing on the same line.
> - A semicolon is not implied at the end of a line if the first token of the subsequent line can be parsed as part of the same statement.

## [TSLint Semicolon Rule](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/semicolon/)

TSLint (used by VS Code) supports a [semicolon rule](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/semicolon/). In `tslint.json`, the semicolon rules may be configured as:

> - "`always`" enforces semicolons at the end of every statement.
> - "`never`" disallows semicolons at the end of every statement except for when they are necessary.

### Example TSLint Semicolon Rules

```
"semicolon": [true, "never"]
```

```
"semicolon": [true, "always"]
```

```
"semicolon": [true, "always", "ignore-interfaces"]
```

## [TSLint being deprecated in 2019](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/4534)

TSLint will be deprecated in 2019 and migrated to ESLint, which will be the standard linter for both TypeScript and JavaScript.

The tool [`tslint-to-eslint-config`](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/tslint-to-eslint-config) helps convert TSLint configurations to the ESLint equivalent.

#### Usage

```
npx tslint-to-eslint-config
```

Comment: "semicolon": [true, "never"] in tslin.json will cause it to complain about existing semicolons.
Is there an option to tell it don't care about them whether there or not, I plan to NEVER NEVER NEVER use semicolons from this point on. AND I will not write stupid code that requires them ;-)
How about ESlint?  Thanks.

Comment: @Meryan Maybe this solution will work for you: [ESLint turn off semicolon rule](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59117668/1164465)

Answer (score 0):

**You can simply disable tslint using**

> tslint:disable */ - Disable all rules for the rest of the file

**also can disable particular rule of tslint..**

> /* tslint:enable:rule1 rule2 rule3... */ - Enable the listed rules for
>   the rest of the file

Answer (score 0):

Semicolon is not required by JavaScript or Typescript but it's considered a good practice by some developers as it makes the code more readable. You can disable the semicolon rule by editing the rule:

```
"semicolon": [true, "never"]
```

For more information on the rule https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/semicolon/

> Is this an issue if I omit the semicolon?

It is not an issue if you omit the semicolon.