# ESLint turn off semicolon rule

Tags: javascript, eslint

When I search for turning off semicolon, I get `"semi": 0` or similar
I tried to putting it, but still my linter puts semicolon on lines.

Below is my .eslintrc and I am perplexed which rule is putting semicolon.

```
{
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 8,
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true,
      "jsx": true
    },
    "sourceType": "module"
  },

  "plugins": [
    "react"
  ],

  "rules": {
    "jsx-quotes": ["error", "prefer-single"],
    "react/jsx-boolean-value": "error",
    "react/jsx-curly-spacing": ["error", "never"],
    "react/jsx-equals-spacing": ["error", "never"],
    "react/jsx-indent": ["error", 2],
    "react/jsx-indent-props": ["error", 2],
    "react/jsx-no-duplicate-props": "error",
    "react/jsx-no-undef": "error",
    "react/jsx-tag-spacing": ["error", { "beforeSelfClosing": "always" }],
    "react/jsx-uses-react": "error",
    "react/jsx-uses-vars": "error",
    "react/self-closing-comp": "error",
    "no-console": 0,
    "semi": 0
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio Code? If so you probably need to configure it so it can understand what your es-lint says.

Comment: Make sure prettier also has the `"semi": false` rule set

Comment: Your IDE can use separate .eslintrc file, I working from terminal and often see problems with eslint after commits from other devs. Run eslint as npm script in terminal and check if it still looking for semi rule.

Comment: Linting and formatting are not the same thing, are you using `prettier` to format in VSCode?

Comment: I run eslint --print-config my-file.js and it has `    "semi": [
      0
    ]` I'm on emacs,

Comment: @Volper what do you mean `prettier` has semi rule? Is there something else than what I have above?

Comment: @eugene you said your linter puts semicolons on lines, but as far as I know, linters only check for errors. So I thought you had prettier installed which automatically formats your code when you save the file.

Comment: @Volper Oh i didn't know such a thing existed. very awesome.. Yes it was prettier in work. thanks for the direction

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try to add this rule:
        "semi": [
            "error",
            "never"
        ]

If still not fixed, the problem may be that **prettier**(if you installed) or editor is controlling it.

Go at vscode settings and add

```
"eslint.autoFixOnSave": true,
```

Comment: Currently you need to write this:
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
  "source.fixAll.eslint": true
 }
instead

Comment: The strange is that when I use `semi: ["error", "never"],`, it automatically deletes the semi colon, however, prettier then warns for a semicolon and if I save second time, it will add it. I tried to set `prettier.semi = fasle` in the vs code settings.json, but no success.

If I use `semi: ["never"],` only, then it just does not make any actions related to the semi colons, not deleting, neither adding.
**EDIT**
Found that the `"@vue/eslint-config-prettier"` in my `.eslintrc` is doing the mess